# Best way to store currency values on MySql database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on an application where we have some services that requires a monetary value to calculate budgets for services. Currently we are using columns `DECIMAL(10,2)`.

While analysing some of the generated budgets I've noticed some of them returns values like `180.0000000024`.

Reading on other questions, I've only found the same type of answers, to go with decimals. In a few cases I saw a recomendation to use `INT` (or similar) instead. The reason is because the calculations will be more precise.

Example: `$64.58` + `$348.99` would be calculated like `6458` + `34899` and stored the result `41357` and later on converted to `413.57`.

So it left mw with this questions, on which is the best way to store currency values on the database. Is `DECIMAL` really the best way? How much of a problem those extra decimals values can be a problem? Is `INT` (or similar) type going to improve something?

Comment: DECIMAL(19,4) is the standard in the Java world

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  If it is a single currency, then use `DECIMAL(m,n)` with `m` and `n` suitably chosen.  If different currencies are stored in the same column, values for `m` and `n` become messy.  And you can run into rounding issues -- because of different laws.

`DECIMAL` goes through a package that does `INT`-like stuff transparently.  `DECIMAL(19,4)` will be stored in

```
6 digits in (effectively) a `MEDIUMINT` (high-order digits)
9 digits in (effectively) a `INT`
4 digits in (effectively) a `SHORTINT`  (after the decimal point)
```

Comment: A rule of thumb:  `DECIMAL(m,n)` takes about `m/2` bytes.  In this example (3+4+2) = 9 bytes ~= 19/2.